# Ошибка на Windows XP

Tags: windows, winapi, c++

Кто может подсказать в чем проблема. На C++ Win32 API написал программку в среде VS 2008. Стоит система Windows 7. Все прекрасно работает на разных компьютерах с Windows 7. Но стоит запустить файл из под XP, то он запускается, я ввожу данные, жму "ок" и ошибка: приложение завершает свою работу, выскакивает стандартное окно ошибки майкрасофт.

Comment: 1. Установите на XP VS2008<p>
2. Запустите программу в режиме отладки

Comment: а без установке не как? может можно узнать как то кикие файлы нужно добавить в систему что бы работало
P.S. Дело в том что писал прогу преподу и он точно не захочет ставить такии программы.

Comment: А Вы на свой компьютер XР поставьте. Можно в виртуальную машину, чтоб не сносить основную ОС или переразбивать винчестер на разделы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, проблема решилась. Установил на хр студию и там отладил. Было деление нуль. После объявления некотрых переменных через static все прошло.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, дело в неаккуратной работе с памятью и/или её освобождением. Семерка многие такие ошибки "проглатывает", в то время как XP громко падает. Как рекомедация - собрать Release с отладочной информацией, запустить программу на XP под отладчиком (можно через удаленную отладку) и включить остановку при возникновении всех исключений. Очень часто бывает, что падает не в месте исключения, а сильно потом, поскольку само исключение "съедается" конструкцией catch(...), но его последствия никуда не деваются.

Answer (score 0):

Это вполне может быть в том случае, если программа динамически подгружает библиотеки, которые есть на Windows 7 и которых нет на Windows XP либо их версии существенно отличаются.

Comment: Как узнать чего именно не хватает и закинуть туда куда надо?

Comment: Либо просмотреть код на предмет прямых вызовов Widnows API и проверить, какие вызовы недоступны в XP, либо подключить отладчик (WinDbg, например) и посмотреть, где приложение падает.

Answer (score 0):

Запустить JIT, найти адрес фолта, определить причину, посмотрев на инструкцию, контекст и инфу об фолте. Затем выполнить бактрейс для определения инвалидных аргументов и процедур.